# Is macOS `prefPane` app possible containing virus?

Tags: macos, ios, security, virus, swift

So I came across this unusual program, https://doomlaser.com/cursorcerer-hide-your-cursor-at-will/.

I'd want to install it, however it's built using a macOS feature called `prefPane`, which lets you add a panel to your macOS preference window.

When I install it, it does not warn me or scan for viruses; instead, it asks if I want to install it for this user or all users.

So I was wondering whether this technique might be used to contain any viruses.

Comment: A "Prefpane" is nothing more than an app that is used/accessed only via the System Setting/Preferences window. I have, on occasion, used them to good effect. So it is a legitimate way to install 3rd party software, but only you can decide if the developer is trustworthy enough for your purposes.

Comment: MacOS does check for known malware, but you wouldn't see anything happen at installation time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, yes. A bad actor could create a malicious [preference pane bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Tasks/Creation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000709-BABFCABJ) for macOS.

In practice, this is unlikely.

**If you do not trust the developer and distributor of a piece of software, do not install it.**

See also:

- [Alternatives App Stores (iOS) : Security risks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/274843/1860)
- [What are the risks if you install an app that's not from the App Store?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178088)

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of Cursorcerer and I can assure you that it is a safe app. I've been maintaining it since 2007 and it is used by many, many users across all the various versions of MacOS that have been released since then.

I wrote it for myself, to solve the problem of getting the cursor out of the way, and thought others would find it useful. Hope it works well for you!